# vuejs [v-cloak] css rule hiding my content in sailsjs

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

I've started with a basic:

```
sails new test-project
```

I'm trying to add a page, taking the examples pages as reference. I've added a new vuejs controller in:

```
assets/js/pages/projects/projectlist.page.js
```

with this very basic content :

```
parasails.registerPage('projectlist', {

data: {
},

beforeMount: function() {
   // Attach any initial data from the server.
   _.extend(this, SAILS_LOCALS);
 },

 mounted: async function() {
//…
},
methods: {
  clickAddProjectButton: function() {
    // Open the modal.
    this.goto('/projectlist/new');
  },
 } 
});
```

Under :

```
/views/pages/projects/projectlist.ejs
```

with this content:

```
<div id="project-list" v-cloak>
   <div class="container">
      <h1>Project List</h1>
      <div class="header-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
     @click="clickAddProjectButton()">add project</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the v-cloak directive is not working and my view is not appearing. I see that the HTML is send to the browser but v-cloak hides it.

I guess I'm missing some link to make this working correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: I don't see any `v-cloak` in your code.

Comment: the wired thing is, I also can find no specific code, I only find this CSS rule [v-cloak] { display: none; } (in layout.less)
But on other files in the folder, it works

Comment: That rule is just so that you can add [v-cloak] as an attribute on an html element and cause the element to be hidden until vue has has finished processing the page. Once vue has finished processing the page such an element will then be shown.  So you probably need a different title for this question.

Comment: I figured out, that my vue controller is not called, since I set a breakpoint in the mounted method, which is not called. I guess I need to name this new controller somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are registering `projeclist` through `parasails.registerPage` function and then the ID of the DIV in the view ejs file is `project-list`.

I faced the same problem and solved it by setting the same name in both, so it will be:

```
parasails.registerPage('projectlist', {

data: {
},
.....
```

And in the view ejs file:

```
<div id="projectlist" v-cloak>
   <div class="container">
```